# thread 1: EXC Bad instruction (code = EXC_1386

Tags: ios, swift, runtime-error

The error is on the line of "guard let faceImage = CIImage." I have followed off of vea software on face detection. What is the problem ?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "FaceDetection") // name of first image to check out
    findFace()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func findFace() {

    // guard function = if everything equals to nil, then code will break out of function
    guard let faceImage = CIImage(image: imageView.image!) else {return}
    let accuracy = [CIDetectorAccuracy:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh] // highest accuracy for facial recognition
    let faceDector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: accuracy) // searches for faces in still image/video
    let faces = faceDector?.features(in: faceImage, options: [CIDetectorSmile:true, CIDetectorEyeBlink:true])
    for face in faces as! [CIFaceFeature] {
        if face.hasSmile {
            // if face in picture is smiling
            print("☺️")
        }
        if face.leftEyeClosed  {
            // if left eye is closed on the face in the picture
            print("Left:")
        }
        if face.rightEyeClosed {
            // if right eye is closed on the face in the picture
            print("Right:")
        }
    }
        if faces!.count != 0 {
            // face is only detected
        print("Number of Faces: \(faces!.count)")
        } else {
            // no faces detected
            print("No Faces: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. You are setting `imageView.image` like this:

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "FaceDetection")
```

That line is failing; you have no such image. Thus, `imageView.image` is `nil`. Then later when you say `imageView.image!` you force-unwrap `nil`. That is a crash in Swift, so you crash.

Comment: the faces that I am using in the project are in my assets folder. Is this part of the problem ?

Comment: If imageView.image is nil, and it is force-unwrapped, wouldn't you get a" fatal error: unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping optional value"?

Comment: @penatheboss He is getting it. He just isn't saying so. (He may not even know where to look for it.)

Comment: @Terril320 I can't see your project. You can. Only you can think about _why_ there is no such image. But there is no such image. You can easily prove it with this code: `let im = UIImage(named: "FaceDetection"); if im == nil {print("No such image")}` So I believe I've answered the question you asked.